# Reboot and Select Proper Device (Lubuntu 16.04) won't boot

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, boot-repair

I have Lubuntu 16.04 installed on my PC. And then all of sudden it won't boot into Lubuntu and has **Reboot and Select Proper Device** during boot.

I've already tried **boot-repair** and still it won't boot.

Here's the [paste bin URL](http://paste2.org/BEpLz7W4)

i've run **gnome-disks**, and this is what appears:
[gnome-disk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZR5Y.png)

Comment: In which mode you installed Legacy or UEFI?

Comment: Boot a live Ubuntu ISO and open the gnome disk utility (usually appears on the menu as just "disks") to check the disk integrity. If you boot a live Lubuntu ISO you'll have to install in the live session: sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility

Comment: @xangua i'm currently booting a live Lubuntu ISO,  i already installed it, then what's the next step afterwards?

Comment: @vembutech how do i know w/c mode i installed it in?

Comment: @vembutech what i did was installed

/ - root
swap
/home

in that order

Comment: i just found out that when i tried to reinstall Lubuntu using live Cd it doesn't detect the Hard disk at all, it only shows the usb drive.

Comment: Check in BIOS for the mode.